# Can app creators continue to access my data after I delete their app?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, privacy

I know that once I have subscribed to a given app, that I have granted permissions to the author to access various bits of information.  but,my question is -  what happens when I delete the app from my phone and library?

Is the author of the app simultaneously and unilaterally denied the future ability to gather anything more from my phone?  Is it possible that while the app is deleted,  the app developer is allowed to maintain a mechanism which continues to gather information (and presumably which I was *told* about in the original T's and C's which I agreed to) ?

Answer (score 6):

If the app is deleted, so are all connections to said developer. It wouldn't get through the approval process if it was allowed to continue farming your data, plus it'd need to stay on your phone for this to work.

Comment: Agreed. On a non-jailbroken phone, apps can't leave bits of themselves behind. Deleting an app removes all traces of its code from your device. That said, if they've pulled data from your phone to some remote location, they've still got it. They just can't gather any *more* once their app is removed.

Comment: THank you for the courtesy of your replies.    Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Each app runs in a "sandbox" which isolates it from the rest of the phone / other apps on the phone. Access to the OS is limited by the functions a developer is provided to use. When an app is deleted it's entire sandbox is removed so nothing is left of that application. If however you gave data to the app and the app sent that information to the developer over the internet and/or you gave the app permission to use your facebook data offline for example, the developer could continue to access your facebook data from facebook until you deauthroised that app on the facebook platform for example.

Answer (score -2):

After uninstalling an app I can see that it continues to access the Internet.

Before I uninstall each app now I block its access to the Internet. Later I check my log file and can see each attempt at Internet access. l also have a counter on each app. Many apps show from 6 to 500 attempts per week and some far more. I have even tried good uninstall software. I have also tried to reinstall and uninstall but without result.

Comment: Could you cite a specific app and iOS version where you can reproduce this? It seems highly irregular and something worth investigating if you are able to show that some removals aren’t in fact a removal of the app. Explaining what log file / how you check it might be illuminating for others as well interested in watching.

Comment: On an iphone, that is interesting, would really appreciate more informations about this issue.

Comment: And what "log file" are you consulting that shows these "attempts at Internet access"? To my knowledge, iOS does not keep any such logs.